# How to insert source code in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

Is there a easy way to insert source code with highlight in Google Docs?

Comment: Well, this question is not really a duplicate. The related question asks explicitly for Syntax Highlighting. This question is more generic. And the answer is: Currently this is not possible. You can use plugins which set colors for you, but inside the document this is just text with color, not "code" (pre). This becomes especially relevant, when handling with the document structure in the docs API.

Comment: This question doesn't meet the [current quality standards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error). Nowadays this might be a trivial question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not directly but there is an easy way to do it.

You can use the online [Colorer-take5 HTML generator](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/php/) to produce the highlighted code. Afterwards just copy/paste it into your document, but don't forget to change the font to `Courier New` and probably reducing the size of it and you're done.

Here is an example for Java code and using the Eclipse style:
[image]

Comment: Great idea, but I would suggest http://pygments.org/ to generate colored HTML (with multiple styles) and Consolas as font.

Comment: I used Microsoft word for this. Pasted my code in Microsoft word and then copy/paste in google docs

Answer (score 59):

With the new [Add-Ons for Google Drive](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.no/2014/03/bring-little-something-extra-to-docs.html), you can get code highlighting with the [Code Pretty add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/code-pretty/igjbncgfgnfpbnifnnlcmjfbnidkndnh?utm_source=permalink).

After installing it, you can access the add-on by clicking *Add-ons → Code Pretty*, → *Format Selection*:
[image: Screenshot of using the add-on]

This results in:
[image: Result of using the add-on]

Comment: This is a much better answer!

Comment: It is but in defense of @Lipis he answered back in 2010.

Comment: Doesn't support code on dark background

Comment: @IgorVaschuk, for me it does (for instance, I use PyCharm with the Darkula theme). I just need to cancel the highlighting in the google doc.

Comment: Dead link. Please fix

Comment: 'CodePretty' is no longer around, [CodeBlocks](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/code_blocks/100740430168) is another option

Comment: This question is 8 years old. Agree, lately [Code Blocks](https://www.alexwforsythe.com/code-blocks/) is so much better.