# How to number lines in formatted code in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

There is a few questions regarding inserting and appropriately formatting code in Google Docs ([here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8429/how-to-insert-source-code-in-google-docs) and [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19241/how-can-i-get-code-syntax-highlighting-in-google-docs) for example).  Indeed there is a very useful Google-Docs add-on called [Code Blocks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/code-blocks/ebieibfdjgmmimpldgengceekpfefmfd) which works very well.

However, I would like the option to number the lines of code.

I got the idea from the output seen [on this page](https://wellsb.com/csharp/beginners/create-menu-csharp-console-application/) (scroll down a bit and you 'll see what I mean).  I am writing student notes for a beginners class I am teaching and it would be helpful to have similar numbers in the code formatted by Code Blocks within Google Docs.

I searched for a solution ([this thread](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-add-line-numbers-in-Google-Docs) seemed promising, but no real solution).

Does anyone know of a way to have formatted code with numbered lines in Google Docs?

An (easily attainable) output like this would be ideal:

[image]

Thanks.

PS - I also searched for a 'reverse' solution, i.e. copy code WITH line numbers.  My IDE is Visual Studio 2017 Community edition - and it doesn't seem to provide this option, I have only found extensions which work for Visual Studio Code (an altogether different application).  However, it would be better to find a way to 'add' line numbers in google docs - this way one would not be restricted by the IDE/editor.  Copying code and pasting in an editor and then re-copying **with** line numbers would be a choice, but way too cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I use is [codepad.org](https://codepad.org). 
I paste the code, select the language and then the website outputs the code in a colour coded way along with the line numbers.

1. I paste the code:

[image: I pasted my code here.]

2. Then Copy the formatted code (If you want the line numbers, then include them in your selection too):

[image]

3. Pasting it in Google Docs will add it as a table preserving all the formatting.

[image]

You can use other "syntax highlighters" too, but when pasting the code in Google Docs, you may have to adjust some line numbers manually.

Comment: Interesting idea, however it's a pity that codepad has support only for a few languages - I 'm quite unlucky, cause the two languages I was interested in, C# and Java, don't seem to be supported ..

Comment: @thomas , then maybe you can try other "syntax highlighter".
Another thing that I have noticed is, that I have my PyCharm's theme dark, and when I copy-pasted the code to Docs, it was copied along with the text colors and the dark background color (but not the line numbers though)

Answer (score 0):

What I do:

- Prepare a list of numbers each in a new line (1, 2, 3, ...), on an editor.
- Create a 1x2 table in Google Docs.
- Paste the code to the second column.
- Paste the numbers to the first column.
- Adjust the column widths.

Result:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

I used vim to open up the file and then use the **mouse** to highlight the text and copy and paste. The mouse needs to be used to highlight everything as vim's inbuilt highlight will not include the line numbers.